# How to use .htaccess to rewrite URL's with @username

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have a profile system in PHP.
If you want to access their profile, you have to goto /profile.php?user=username
I want to be able to rewrite this /@username.

Currently, my .htaccess code is this:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
    RewriteRule ^@(.*)$ profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

FIXED: I had to change AllowOverride to All in my apache configuration.

```
<Directory /path/to/directory>
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

and changed my htaccess file to: (thanks to the person who answered this question)

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^@(.*)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Not sure why you have `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]` rule in your htaccess file. This means it will forbid any page which is satisfying your 2 mentioned conditions. IMHO this shouldn't be there in your rules file(at least for rewrite which you asked in your question).

Answer (score 2):

As per your shown samples could you please try following. Where considering that you are hitting URL like `http://localhost:80/@test"` which you want it to be served by `http://localhost:80/profile.php?user=$1`

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^@(.*)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Also as mentioned in comments you don't want to use `[F]` rule of yours shown sample htaccess so I had removed if from here.

Comment: @PrestonCammarata, could you please do let me know if your profile.php is present in same level where htaccess file is?

Comment: yes. it is. im running this web server with apache on digitalocean vps if that helps..

Comment: @PrestonCammarata, rules look fine to me, could you please confirm which sample URL you are hitting once here.

Comment: website.com/@user

Comment: do you think i need to enable anything in apache??

Comment: @PrestonCammarata, ok let's do one check first. Could you please put some junk characters like `---------------------` in your .htaccess file save it and then try any URL of you get 500 internal server error then it means your htaccess is working else it's NOT enabled itself. Let me know how it goes then?

Comment: i edited my /etc/apache2/sites-available/mywebsitehere.conf file, and added AllowOverride All in between these two tags <Directory /path/to/dir> </Directory> and now it WORKS!!